# Why am I getting "key not found" errors after re-installing MySQL using homebrew on Mac M1 Pro?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, homebrew

I cleaned up the local development system on my Mac M1 Pro recently and also reinstalled MySQL using [homebrew](https://brew.sh) (I think the native package was installed previously, but I am not sure).

Unfortunately, I am getting some nasty errors in my Ruby on Rails 7 apps all over the place now. All databases are setup correctly using the lasted flavor of MySQL 8.3. I can access the data outside of rails.

However, no data can actually be accessed or read via the rails app. This is the error I am getting all over the place:

> KeyError in PagesController#pricing key not found: :Field Did you
> mean? :"Field\x00\x00"

[image]

Can anybody tell me what I am missing here?

I've already searched for hours but to no avail. There are no errors in the MySQL logs, so it's probably a Rails issue? I am using Ruby version 3.2.2 by the way.

```
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/schema_statements.rb:179:in `fetch'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql/schema_statements.rb:179:in `new_column_from_field'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:111:in `block in columns'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:108:in `each'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:108:in `each_hash'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:110:in `each'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:110:in `map'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:110:in `columns'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:346:in `block in columns'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:345:in `fetch'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:345:in `columns'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:354:in `block in columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:353:in `fetch'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:353:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:58:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/schema_cache.rb:188:in `columns_hash'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:618:in `load_schema!'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/attributes.rb:264:in `load_schema!'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/encryption/encryptable_record.rb:127:in `load_schema!'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:563:in `block in load_schema'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:560:in `synchronize'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:560:in `load_schema'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:499:in `_default_attributes'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:418:in `attributes_builder'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:639:in `instantiate_instance_of'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/querying.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in _load_from_sql'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/result.rb:72:in `each'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/result.rb:72:in `each'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/querying.rb:84:in `map'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/querying.rb:84:in `block in _load_from_sql'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/querying.rb:79:in `_load_from_sql'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:1010:in `instantiate_records'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:965:in `block in exec_queries'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:1018:in `skip_query_cache_if_necessary'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:956:in `exec_queries'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:742:in `load'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation.rb:264:in `records'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:100:in `each'
app/views/shared/_plans.html.erb:3
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:264:in `public_send'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:264:in `_run'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:261:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:549:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:249:in `render'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:252:in `block in render_partial_template'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:246:in `render_partial_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:237:in `render'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:83:in `render_partial_to_object'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:55:in `render_partial'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:44:in `render'
app/views/pages/pricing.html.erb:6
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:264:in `public_send'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:264:in `_run'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:261:in `block in render'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:549:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:249:in `render'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:60:in `block in render_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:76:in `block in render_with_layout'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:75:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:59:in `render_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:11:in `render'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:63:in `render_template_to_object'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:31:in `render_to_object'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:135:in `block in _render_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/base.rb:291:in `in_rendering_context'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:134:in `_render_template'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:256:in `_render_template'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:121:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:158:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:27:in `render'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:139:in `render'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in render'
/Users/timo/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/benchmark.rb:311:in `realtime'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `block in render'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:98:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:39:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:28:in `render'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:37:in `default_render'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:7:in `send_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:224:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:165:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:259:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:121:in `block in run_callbacks'
i18n (1.14.1) lib/i18n.rb:322:in `with_locale'
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:40:in `set_locale'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `block in run_callbacks'
actiontext (7.1.3) lib/action_text/rendering.rb:23:in `with_renderer'
actiontext (7.1.3) lib/action_text/engine.rb:69:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Engine>'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:130:in `block in run_callbacks'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:141:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:258:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:25:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:74:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:58:in `instrument'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:73:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:261:in `process_action'
activerecord (7.1.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:160:in `process'
actionview (7.1.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:40:in `process'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:227:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:309:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:49:in `dispatch'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:51:in `block in serve'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:131:in `block in find_routes'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:124:in `each'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:124:in `find_routes'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:882:in `call'
bullet (7.1.6) lib/bullet/rack.rb:14:in `call'
rack-attack (6.7.0) lib/rack/attack.rb:127:in `call'
http_accept_language (2.1.1) lib/http_accept_language/middleware.rb:14:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/etag.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/permissions_policy.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:33:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:266:in `context'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:689:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (7.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
railties (7.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:39:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:135:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.1.3) lib/active_support/broadcast_logger.rb:240:in `method_missing'
railties (7.1.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.4.2) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:92:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:28:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:59:in `block in call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:24:in `collect_events'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/server_timing.rb:58:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.1.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:141:in `call'
rack-mini-profiler (3.3.0) lib/mini_profiler.rb:334:in `call'
railties (7.1.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:536:in `call'
puma (5.6.8) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.8) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.8) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.8) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.8) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.8) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: I have a Mac1 Pro -- however I run all my databases in docker containers. if you don't want to go that route, check this out -- https://rasmuskjellberg.se/installing-ruby-on-rails-with-mysql-on-macos-intel-apple-silicon-152d9aedc591 -- seems you need to goose the homebrew installation.

Comment: FWIW, the stack you have usually "just works". Homebrew installs `mysql_config` which provides all the right paths for the bundle install of `mysql2`. The suggestion that your `column_definitions` have a `:Field\x00\x00` key instead of a `:Field` key makes me wonder if this isn't some encoding / character set thing. Basically Rails is getting the output of `SHOW FULL FIELDS FROM 'plans'` and somehow getting two nulls (`\x00`) appended to the end of the column names. Tricky to troubleshoot that from here.

Comment: Same problem here, maybe the mysql2 gem needs another update?

Comment: Yeah, I also think it's the `mysql2` gem. I simply couldn't get it to install properly on my M1 Pro on Mac OS 14.3 (and I've tried for three days!). My solution for now is to completely remove MySQL from homebrew (using [this guide](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/)) and simply install the [package download from the MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (make sure to select the `ARM` version if you  are on Apple silicon). That took me literally only 5 minutes to setup and you even get a free server toggle button in your Mac OS settings.

Comment: I also added `export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql/bin/` to my `.zshrc` profile, so I can use the `mysql` command in the terminal. I will give the homebrew installation another try in the next couple of weeks when the `mysql2` gem will hopefully be fixed.